# Expresso Store order_shipping is zero after country change

Tags: expresso-store, shipping, update

I'm testing a site with Store and the AUS Post extension. Customers enter billing and shipping addresses, then choose the shipping method on the next page. Shipping within AUS is set to a low flat rate per item, and shipping to other countries calculated by weight. If an AUS order for local delivery is created but not paid, then someone goes back and adds more items, it's fine - the shipping cost is recalculated.

But if someone goes back and just changes the shipping country (e.g. Australia to Austria - so similar!), the shipping cost goes to zero. This is clearly wrong, but I don't know why it's happening. Does anyone know a fix, or else a way to get Store to recalculate the shipping_order? I can't force this by re-setting shipping_method, because this can only be done once for a new cart.

**Update:** 
After the shipping has been calculated I can check if order_subtotal == order_total. As there should always be a shipping cost, I can show a warning and a link back to shipping details instead of a submit button.
Testing if order_shipping_total > 0 doesn't give a proper result, probably because the field includes a currency symbol etc.
(later) ...Well the above check is OK, but it looks as if the Australia Post Extension stopped working for me a while ago. It was OK to begin with but now it will only deal with a rate per item. I've tried reinstalling it but that hasn't made any difference.

Comment: I have not worked with the Australia Post Extension personally but if you are going to use any value as a conditional on Store  you will want to add `_val` to your fields. I am on my phone so I apologize if this is not formatted correctly but something. Along the lines of `{if order_shipping_total_val > 0}next link{else}update cart link which should shipping methods{/if}`

Comment: Interesting! I'll give it a go. Thanks for the suggestion, and also thanks for your articles about using Expresso Store.